# Android getIntent() Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, nullpointerexception

In my MainActivity I've got a ListView and a OnClickListenter. Via Button it is possible to change to another site(addRecord.xml), which is adding a new record in the database (and ListView).

When clicking (and holding) on a item, you get to the same site as when adding a new record. (see above).
Everything until here works fine.
Now I tried to add a new Intent because the EditTexts in the  (addRecord.xml) should be filled with the data of the Item of the ListView which is clicked(longclick).

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityAddRecord.class);
                    i.putExtra("Name",  arrayList.get(position).getName());
                    i.putExtra("update", true);
                    startActivity(i);
```

in the ActivityAddRecord class I've added:

```
  Intent i = getIntent();
       final boolean update = i.getExtras().getBoolean("update");
       if(update==true)
       {
           editText1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name"));  
       }
```

Now when clicking and holding on a ListView item you get to the addrecord.xml site and the EditText is filled with the Name. It works fine.

But when I want to add a new Record (via Button click) the App crashes. Without these 6 lines of code it's not crashing.

In LogCat it shows NullPointerException at Line 52 which is

```
final boolean update = i.getExtras().getBoolean("update");
```

I've read a lot of topics about this kind of error, but the soulutions didn't help me

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `i.getBooleanExtra` and `i.getStringExtra`, since you did not provide a Bundle (you did not call `i.setExtras(Bundle)` )

Answer (score 3):

Replace `final boolean update = i.getExtras().getBoolean("update");`

by

`final boolean update = i.getBooleanExtra("update");`

Also `editText1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name"));`

by

`editText1.setText(i.getStringExtra("Name"));`

Answer (score 1):

```
   Intent i = getIntent();
   final boolean update =i.getBooleanExtra("update",false);
   if(update==true)
   {
       editText1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name"));  
   }
```

Please Use This for your Requirement..It will Works fine.